# Redirect all the pages to the single page using htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using WordPress and I have to redirect all the pages to the index.html page (I created in the root folder for temporary).

I tried the below code but it's redirecting only the home page.

```
Redirect 301 "index.html" "https://www.examle.com"
```

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.examle.com/$1 [R=permanent,L] //getting error(The page isn’t redirecting properly)
```

I tried the below code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.html$ 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^00.00.00.00   //my ip
RewriteRule $ /index.html [R=302,L]
```

Any other solution to redirect all pages to index.html? I have more than 50 pages on my website. I want to redirect all on the index.html

Comment: Can you share the content of your current .htaccess file?

Comment: @ozgur, I tried all the above one by one and RewriteEngine On at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite your existing `.htaccess` file content with this. Please note that this code assumes that your wordpress is installed on the `root directory`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule . /index.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I tried your code but the issue is, If I access  https://examle.com/about  then I am getting the mine about us page. General, it should be redirected to the index.html page

Comment: Yes, I want all the pages to redirect to the index.html page.